# Confusion about bundler path

Tags: passenger, bundler, rack

I opened a dedicated hosting account on DreamHost. I deployed an rails app to that. I got the following error.

```
You have already activated rack 1.2.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.6. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

I checked the version.

```
$ gem list -d rack

rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
    Author: Christian Neukirchen
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rack
    Homepage: http://rack.rubyforge.org
    Installed at (1.2.1): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
                 (1.1.0): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
                 (1.0.1): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
                 (1.0.0): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Rack 1.3.6 is not there. But when I checked it with "bundle show" it's already installed. (Actually I did "bundle install --deployment")

```
$ bundle show rack
/.../my_rails_app_root/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6
```

And I have config/setup_load_paths.rb

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```

Actually I found a solution. Just "gem install rack -v 1.3.6" fixed the problem.

But why does passenger pick up system's rack gem(or user's rack gem) instead of bundle's rack gem? How do you avoid this problem?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: I tried installing Rack 1.3.6 and that didn't work for me. It's still saying that it's "already activated rack 1.2.1".

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is what you get when you run your app (e.g. **rails server**) without prefixing the command with **bundle exec**.

When you ran **bundle install --deployment**, bundler took your gems from **./vendor/cache** and whacked them in **./vendor/bundle**. From then on, Bundler knows where to find them, but you have to be running the app through Bundler.

Rubygems, however, does not know where these gems are, which is why they are not shown when you run the rubygems command **gem list**. When you installed Rack 1.3.6 using rubygems, naturally rubygems found it and your app started working.

Not using bundler to start your app lets rubygems satisfy the requirements of your app according to it's own method, and that is a fairly random - I would be quite surprised if your app is currently running all the same gem versions that you ran your tests on, for instance (Eek!)

The approach I usually take is to uninstall *all* the gems from the server, install a single version of rubygems and bundler, and then rely exclusively on Bundler to maintain my app's gems. The beauty of bundler is that it calculates a valid set of gems and reliably uses it.

Hope this helps!